# Find Time Period Count Between Specific Dates

Tags: t-sql, datetime

How can we find count of time period (etc. ***12:00 PM - 01:00 PM***) between two datetime values in T-Sql?

For example;

We choose "***10/07/2015 12:00 AM***" as start datetime (*this value is parametrical*) and we choose "***10/09/2015 12:00 AM***" as end datetime (*this value is parametrical*)

We want to learn count of time period (12:00 PM - 01:00 PM).

In this example;

*10/07/2015 12:00 PM - 10/07/2015 01:00 PM* (First)

*10/08/2015 12:00 PM - 10/08/2015 01:00 PM* (Second)

And we have to get "two".

Can you help about this?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @a datetime = '2015-01-01 12:00:00'
declare @b datetime = '2015-02-01 13:00:00'

select datediff(HOUR, @a, @b)
```

You can check the interval types you can use with datediff(...) function:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx